# Transações no SQL Server, como funcionam?

Tags: sql-server, transações

Estou com dificuldade para entender esse conteúdo na faculdade e em encontrar bons materiais para conseguir entender, alguém poderia me explicar de uma forma melhor como são especificados transações e definidos os delimitadores no SGBD, em específico o SQL Server? Como ele trata também o nível de concorrência, e o controle do nível de concorrência?

Comment: Já buscou no [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=transactions&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4#refinementChanges=49&pageNumber=1&showMore=false) ?

Comment: O ideia básica de uma transction é garantir que todas as operações de uma sequencia sejam feitas , o exemplo clássico é uma tranferência bancaria , será feito um débito numa conta e um crédito em outra , se por algum motivo a segunda operação falhar a primeira precisa ser desfeita. Em geral a melhor fonte neste caso é a documentação oficial do SGBD em questão.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188929.aspx

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada @gmsantos

Comment: Vou ver esse link @motta